# jQuery - Find .attr of the last-child element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get by jQuery the `.attr("msg_g")` of the last-child element

```
<div id="append">
  <div class="h" msg_g="1">A</div>
  <div class="y" msg_g="2">B</div>
  <div class="h" msg_g="3">C</div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that script below must work but returns me **undefined**

```
var msg_g = $( "#append div:last-child" ).attr( "msg_g" );
console.log(msg_g);
```

I use the script below for checking if last-child 'hasClass' and works perfect, why doesn't work on .attr()

Example for `.hasClass()`

```
if($( "#append div:last-child" ).hasClass( "y" )){
    var last_msg_class="by_you";
}else if($( "#append div:last-child" ).hasClass( "h" )){
    var last_msg_class="by_friend";
}
```

Comment: first of all its better if you use custom attributes to add the `data-` prefix before it. Its more common used.

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/a1u7x28c/, where exactly do you call `var msg_g = $( "#append div:last-child" ).attr( "msg_g" );`?

Comment: Copy of my last comment:
Thank you for the answer but in my case doesn't work, I'm using it onClick event to use function and in this function to get values from different elements. With the example above data-* works but doesn't with attr, can't find the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `msg_g` attribute,try using `data-*` attribute.

Modify your html as :--

```
<div id="append">
<div class="h" data-msg_g="1">A</div>
<div class="y" data-msg_g="2">B</div>
<div class="h" data-msg_g="3">C</div>
</div>
```

and try this in Jquery :--

```
var msg_g = $( "#append > div:last" ).data( "msg_g" );
```

and make sure that you're Jquery code is inside `document.ready` block.

Comment: How will this solve the problem? While I agree that `data-XXX` attributes are preferred, the original code should still work. This should just be a comment, not an answer, and someone already made that comment.

Comment: Thank you with data-* works perfect. I still don't realize why with attr() doesn't work, but nevermind, Thank you again!

Comment: @Barmar...besides including jquery code inside `document.ready` block i don't think there is any problem in question and i included that in my answer too and someone in comments has given fiddle link also...i am just providing here a more efficient way of writing same code...by modifying the OP code...although the timings of the comment which you are pointing is almost the same as my answer timings but with this answer atleast OP come to know complete usage of `data-*`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code runs after dom ready. If your script executes before the rendering of elements, problems will occur.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#append > div:last").attr("msg_g");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it, and its working. Make sure that your code is executes when DOM element is ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var msg_g = $( "#append div:last-child" ).attr( "msg_g" );
    alert(msg_g);
});
```

Check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ytj8z0j7/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in my case doesn't work, I'm using it onClick event to use function and in this function to get values from different elements. With the example above data-* works but doesn't with attr, can't find the logic.